# Why Behat\Mink\Element\NodeElement:setValue removes dashes from passed value?

Tags: php, html, selenium, phantomjs, behat

I'm using Behat: `3.0.15` with Selenium `3.4` and PhantomJS as a browser.

I have custom step to populate value of input date field. Basically it's one line:

```
$element->setValue('1999-01-01');
```

I've noticed in next scenario step that result value is 19990101 and my field isn't passed validation.

Comment: There is a date picker for setting this value. Using javascript to populate field value works and validation is ok. Strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Because `setValue` doesn't just "set a value" in the field

If you look at the implementation of the `setValue` function in `Selenium2Driver`, you'll find that the actual value being input is defined in the following code:

```
if (in_array($elementName, array('input', 'textarea'))) {
    $existingValueLength = strlen($element->attribute('value'));
        // Add the TAB key to ensure we unfocus the field as browsers are triggering the change event only
        // after leaving the field.
    $value = str_repeat(Key::BACKSPACE . Key::DELETE, $existingValueLength) . $value . Key::TAB;
}
```

Therefore, if you have some JS handling of keyboard input in the field, `setValue` might produce strange results.